# Multiple events that have the same cause

Tags: java, swing, awt

This code does something that could throw an exception, when `field` loses focus.

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();

field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt){

    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt){
        try{
            doSomething();
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }

});
```

But if `field` loses focus due to a button press, and `doSomething()` throws an exception,
I want the button to have no effect.
Is this possible?

Comment: In a round about way, maybe.  A better solution "might" be to use a `InputVerifier` which can control if focus should be moved from the field, although I kind of hate it (as I don't tend to think in a linear manner so will jump around fields

Comment: Thank you, @MadProgrammer. `InputVerifier` is an excellent solution.